# What dunder method to use in Python to return an attribute of the object?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a "CumulativeMovingAverage" class. That's what I did:

```
class CumulativeMovingAverage():
    cma = None
    n = 0
    def add(self, *args):
        if self.cma is None:
            self.cma = args[0]

        else:
            self.cma = (args[0] + self.n*self.cma) / (self.n+1)
        self.n += 1
        return None

    def __call__(self):
        return self.cma
```

It works like this:

```
a = CumulativeMovingAverage()
a.add(2)
a.add(4)
a.cma ==> 3
a() ==> 3
```

I would like to overwrite a dunder method such that

`a ==> 3`
and also

```
b = a + 100
b ==> 103
```

That is, without having to call a with parenthesis. Is it possible? What dunder should I overwrite?

Comment: Well, `a` itself won't be `3`, it will always be an instance of `CumulativeMovingAverage`. You can customise it's *appearance* (`__str__`, `__repr__`), or its *value as a number* (`__int__`, `__float__`), or its behaviour when using the `+` operator (`__add__` etc.)… See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names for all possibilities…

Comment: So is this something that only built in types can do? For example, `a = [2, 3]` is of type `list` but just evaluating `a` will return the list, not it's object type.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by that. If you `print()` a list, its `__repr__` implementation will take care to produce something that looks like a list literal. Your class can do the same. The only difference is that there's a specific literal for lists (`[]`), which your class doesn't have. So at best your class' `__repr__` could return something like `'CumulativeMovingAverage(4)'`.

Comment: I mean, your class *could* implement `def __repr__(self): return str(self.cma)`. Then whenever your print it, it'll just show up as `4`. But since that's rather misleading, your class *should* implement it as something like `return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.cma})'`…

Comment: So it seems that the only way to achieve what I want is to implement a bunch of under such as `__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__mul__`, `__add__`, and like 20 more of them, all containing `self.cma > other` etc. Correct?

Comment: If you want the complete behaviour of a number, pretty much. There are shortcuts to some of those, like `total_ordering`, or perhaps even subclassing `int` in some way to inherit most of this behaviour for free.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking about subclassing int/float. I'll give it a try, thank you!